# How can I get the byte size of an operand in IDA Pro?

Tags: ida, idapython, elf

I am trying to get the byte size of all operands in a given instruction from IDA Pro. At first I tried using `GetOperandValue(ea,n)` to see how large the value was and calculate how many bytes were necessary to store that value, but it doesn't return leading zeros, which means that it doesn't work.

Now I am trying to use `OpHex(ea,n)` to get the answer,  but it's just returning `True` (as do `OpDecimal`, `OpBinary`, and `OpOctal`).

How can I find the number of bytes used for operands of a particular instruction and why is `OpHex` returning true?

**Edit:** My current solution works, but I would still like one that is more technically correct and bulletproof. Right now I am just using `GetOperandValue(ea, op)` to get both operands for all instructions (even if they have neither or only one) and then checking to make sure the operand value is greater than `FF`. If It's greater than `FF` I just assume it is an address, which in this case is four bytes. If both operands meet this condition, I assign the size to be eight bytes.

This works for the moment, but will encounter difficulties in eventual moves to other architectures (right now I'm just working with x86-64).

Comment: Do you mean a value in an opcode instruction like `mov` or the size of a data structure to which some pointer is pointing?

Comment: The size of the operand(s) in an opcode instruction, not the size to which it is pointing. To recreate the relocation I need to know how many bytes to overwrite with addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Module `ida_ua` now contains a function `get_dtype_size`, which seems to implement @WHsT's answer.

Assuming you have an instruction i, you can use it e.g. like this:

`ida_ua.get_dtype_size(i.Op1.dtype))`

Comment: I no longer have the ability to test this; marking as answered, unless someone tags me in the comments that this doesn't work. Thanks @langlauf.io

Answer (score 3):

There doesn't seem to be a straightforward way to achieve this. But you can take a look at [this page](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/sdkdoc/group__dt__.html) of the IDA SDK documentation.

According to the description of the previous page, we can write a little helper function:

```py
def size_of_operand(op):
    tbyte = 8
    dt_ldbl = 8
    n_bytes = [ 1, 2, 4, 4, 8,
            tbyte, -1, 8, 16, -1,
            -1, 6, -1, 4, 4,
            dt_ldbl, 32, 64 ]
    return n_bytes[op.dtype]
```

Now we can use command like

```py
insn = idautils.DecodeInstruction(ScreenEA())
index_of_operand = 0
size_of_operand(insn.Operand[index_of_operand])
```

to get the size of an operand.

For example, for `xor al, al`, it returns 1. For `pop ebp`, it returns 4.

Note: refer to [Porting from IDAPython 6.x-7.3, to 7.4](https://hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/ida74_idapython_no_bc695_porting_guide.shtml)

Answer (score 2):

Are You Loooking for some thing like

```
Message("%s\n" , GetCurrentLine());
Message("%x\n" , ItemSize(ScreenEA()));
```

this will give results as below

```
.text:010328BB 56                            push    esi
1
.text:010328BC BE 10 42 05 01                mov     esi, offset unk_1054210
5
.text:010328C1                               cmp     byte_1054309, bl
6
.text:010328C1 38 1D 09 43 05 01             cmp     byte_1054309, bl
6
```

Note: refer to [Porting from IDAPython 6.x-7.3, to 7.4](https://hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/ida74_idapython_no_bc695_porting_guide.shtml)

Comment: Seems the inquirer is only interested in the size of the _operands_, not the instructions overall. But this is close.

Comment: Yes, @0xC0000022L is correct.